# How to set the datatextfield value instead of the value on a drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a list of countries, which returns an ID and a Name. I also have a string. The drop down sets the value to the ID, but at this point I don't have the ID's. I want to be able to set the selectedvalue as the Text Field. Is there a way to do this? or is there a way to compare my string against the list to work out the ID?

```
string country = "Australia";
ddlCountry.DataSource = listofcountries;
ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Value";
ddlCountry.DataValueField = "Key";
ddlCountry.DataBind();

ddlCounty.SelectedValue = ???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(country).Selected = true
```